# create meeting as Non-login / API User, Cannot resolve method 'loginWithZoom' in 'ZoomSDK'

Tags: zoom-sdk, meeting-request

i'm new in zoom sdk i need help, i have 3 questions.

1. i know that to host a scheduled meeting as a non-login user, i need to retrieve User_ID, ZAK

to get user_id, get request to https://api.zoom.us/v2/users.

it means get already created user's user_id?

2. is there any way to host not sign up zoom account?

i just integrate zoom sdk in my app, and i want to let users who using my app create meeting  any sign in zoom, is it possible?

3. i want to use Email Login so, I coded it like this.

```
private void Login(String email, String pw){
    int result = ZoomSDK.getInstance().loginWithZoom(email, pw);
    if(result == ZoomApiError.ZOOM_API_ERROR_SUCCESS){
        ZoomSDK.getInstance().addAuthenticationListener(authLitener);
    }
}
```

but, i encountered this message

Cannot resolve method 'loginWithZoom' in 'ZoomSDK'(other method work well)

how to host meeting with email, pw?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zoom has removed the create meeting functionality from ZoomSDK. You need to use Zoom Apis to create or schedule meetings.
Also, zoom has removed login with email password in v5.9.0. Hope they provide an alternate solution.

-------------- Zoom Release Note ----------------

Removed the email login interfaces:

Interfaces in ZoomSDK:

```
- public int loginWithZoom(String email, String password)

- public boolean isEmailLoginEnable()
```

Comment: @jseok How did you proceed with login and create meeting then?

Answer (score 0):

I saw that part of your question mentioned having users authenticate to use your zoom app. There is a way to circumvent the authentication process so
users who are using your App can also use your Zoom app without having to re-Authenticate. This way your users can access the app with either a company email(Domain) or a token. But you will have to be sure you configure your OWASP securely.

To your later part, If you want other members of your organization or users of your app to Create the meetings that is possible. But Zoom is role-based so if you want someone to create a meeting you will have to allow other users the host role. Most of Zooms APIs can only be accessed by the host.